# Get X's configuration

Tags: fedora, arch-linux, x11, xorg, nouveau

I have done some tests with 2 NVIDIA cards (not in SLI) and 4 monitors, with nouveau drivers.

Debian 8 testing and Arch are not able to use the 4 monitors at the same time, but somehow Fedora 21 is able.

So I thought I'd try the config that Fedora is using with Arch and see if my monitors start working, but for that I must get the config that X is using in Fedora.

How can I get the config? (I tried `X :1 -configure` and then reading the file that is generated in `/root/xorg.conf.new`, but that doesn't seem to make my 4 monitors work)

Comment: Yes, I did that. I switch to init3 with `Ctrl + Alt + F2` and then ran the command and it generated a conf file. Should I be doing it differently?

Comment: I tried what you said, but I got exactly the same result.